# Failed to rename image and upload using storeAs in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload

I created a form to store article with an image , and generate a resized version as thumbnail from it.

I want the image to be renamed after the article slug and stored in the "public/img/articles-images " directory but i keep receiving : "Image source not readable" error

*This is the image upload handler function in my controller :*

```
private function handleRequest($request)
{
   $data = $request->all();
   if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
    $image = $request->file('image');
    $fileName = $request->slug;

        
    $successUploaded = $image->storeAs('img/articles-images', $fileName);

    if($successUploaded) {
     $width = config('cms.image.thumbnail.width');
     $height = config('cms.image.thumbnail.height');

    $extension = $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $thumbnail = str_replace(".{$extension}", "_thumb.{$extension}", $fileName);

    Image::make('img/articles-images' . '/' . $fileName)
        ->resize($width, $height)
        ->save('img/articles-images' . '/' . $thumbnail);
  }

     $data['image'] = $fileName;
  }

  return $data;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it ! Apparently there was no need to storeAs() method at all , the new code is like below :

```
  if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
      $image = $request->file('image');
      $fileName = $request->slug.'.' .$image->getClientOriginalExtension();

      $destination = $this->uploadPath;

      $successUploaded = $image->move($destination, $fileName);

     // //
```

Answer (score 0):

`storeAs()` method, which receives the path, the file name, and the (optional) disk as its arguments :

```
$successUploaded = $request->file('image')->storeAs(
    'images', $fileName
);
```

Comment: Without the renaming feature , the images were uploading normally to "public/img/articles-images" diretory , therefor 'images' is not the intended directory , also i keep receiving the same error message